# Trouble sharing a variable between 2 nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, parse-platform

I have a function within a function and I have trouble passing a variable through.
I am using jQuery and Parse.com
Here's my code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tokfile;
        Parse.initialize(myApp, myID);
        var some_file = Parse.Object.extend("myApp");
        var query = new Parse.Query(some_file);
        query.equalTo("objectId", "xcxcxcxc");

        query.find
        ({
            success: function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                    console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('some_file'));
                    var myObject = object.get('some_file');
                    var myFile = myObject._url

                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }


        });
        $("#mp3").attr("src", myFile)

    });
</script>

<audio controls preload="none" style="width:480px;">
    <source id="mp3" src="placeholder" type="audio/mp3" />
```

As you might see, I am trying to change the #mp3 id's src to URL that I am getting from Parse.com
Now for some reason I just fail to load it up and the DOM is loaded with the placeholder instead.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: move `$("#mp3").attr("src", myFile)` into the success function

Comment: Hmmm didn't help.. It stills shows the placeholder inside src

Comment: why do you assign the same element's src many times? (should it be after the loop?)

Answer (score 1):

What is changing is the scope of your variable, so put the myFile variable outside of the scope of the request:

```
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tokfile;
            Parse.initialize(myApp, myID);
            var some_file = Parse.Object.extend("myApp");
            var query = new Parse.Query(some_file);
            var myFile;
            query.equalTo("objectId", "xcxcxcxc");

            query.find
            ({
                success: function (results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var object = results[i];
                        console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('some_file'));
                        var myObject = object.get('some_file');
                        var audioElement = document.querySelector('#audioplayer');
                        var source = document.querySelector('#mp3');
                        source.src = myObject._url;
                        audioElement.load();
                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }


            });
            $("#mp3").attr("src", myFile)

        });
    </script>

    <audio controls preload="none" id="audioplayer" style="width:480px;">
        <source id="mp3" src="placeholder" type="audio/mp3" />
```

Comment: that still misses the callback train... you just assign undefined without error by globalizing the variable.

Comment: Is there something else you're doing? I see that the success can contain multiple items, maybe that's why there are problems?

Comment: success actually contains a JSON

Comment: What if you move `$("#mp3").attr("src", myFile)` within the success function, on the line where `myFile = myObject._url`?

Comment: I just updated my answer. The reason you did not see it working is that once you change the URL you also need to 'refresh' the audio item. I also slightly changed the HTML.

Comment: Thanks @johnlocke. Your fix did the job.. I had to load the audioElement indeed! Have a nice weekend

Comment: If this solved your problem, can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the variable scope doesn't help, you are trying to use the value before it exists.

The `query.find` call is asynchronous, so the code that uses the variable will run before the code that assigns the value to the variable.

Use the value inside the callback function:

```
    query.find
    ({
        success: function (results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('some_file'));
                var myObject = object.get('some_file');
                var myFile = myObject._url
                $("#mp3").attr("src", myFile) 
           }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```